# Full Load Amps vs General Purpose Amps

Tags: power, protection, circuit-protection, circuit-breaker

http://www.carlingtech.com/sites/default/files/documents/M-Series_Details_%26_COS_021114.pdf

This circuit breaker have two different current ratings, depending on amperage range: Full Load Amps and General Purpose Amps. What is the difference between them?

Comment: On a different note, what kind of redneck would use the word "Amps [literally]" in a datasheet?..

Comment: @NickAlexeev Most Americans.

Answer (score 4):

"Full load amps" appears to be a term that is applied to large electrical motors.  It is the current that the motor can be expected to draw at its rated power output (like a 3HP motor that is really delivering 3HP of mechanical power to the load.)

Since a motor is largely an inductive load (electrically) and since its current consumption can be expected to vary drastically from the rated current, it makes sense to rate the breaker differently for motors and general purpose electrical loads (lighting, computers, etc.)